# Are there any safer alternatives to hidden input fields for persisting properties across POST requests?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, crud, razor-pages, model-binding

I have run into a problem where post requests in my CRUD app result in data loss due to simply forgetting to add a hidden field inside my `<form>` tags. For example, I have a UserModel that has a DateCreated property which ideally shouldn't be updated after creating the record. But subsequent updates inside my CRUD app led to my UserModel's DateCreated field being set to NULL. This is because there was no `<input asp-for="Input.DateCreated" hidden />` tag that preserved the value of DateCreated across POST requests in my Razor Page. I am hesitant to accept that the best way to solve this problem is just to remember to add hidden input tags for every field you don't want to update. To simply remember to do this seems like an unnecessary risk and bad design.

Some sample code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="AspNetUsersId" hidden />
    <input asp-for="Input.DateCreated" hidden />
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger form-text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-label">First Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger form-text"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-label">Last Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger form-text"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

One solution that came to mind is to start using DTOs for updating which would not include the DateCreated field at all, and would just require the Id property to be included in the hidden fields, but then I run into the problem where I have to make subsequent queries to fetch the remainder of my properties for my UserModel and then map them accordingly and pass that to my Update method.

Or, I could write another update method that would accept an UpdateUserDto.

Is using hidden input tags the best way to persist model properties across post requests or is this problem a result of larger architectural issues?

Comment: Why is your update code changing the value of`DateCreated`?

Comment: @stuartd - Because the ORM takes in a Model which is a representation of the database table and makes updates according to that Model. So if my user model now has a DateCreated property of NULL, the record in my database is going to be updated to NULL. A clear solution to this would be to not use an ORM and write a SQL query myself, but that is ignoring the specific problem I'm encountering.

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext.Update` method is fine where you want all properties to be included in the SQL update command. However, where you only want to enable modification of some properties in the entity, The recommended solution is to attach your entity to the context and then specify which properties might have been modified. That way, only those fields will be included in the generated SQL update command.

```
context.Attach(myEntity);
context.Entry(myEntity).Property(x => x.Name).IsModfied = true;
context.Entry(myEntity).Property(x => x.Description).IsModfied = true;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Including other property values in hidden fields is not a good idea because they can be modified by a user who is familiar with the browser dev tools, for example. Or anyone who can craft an HTTP request.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, although this solution only addresses the case where we are using Entity Framework and I am using Dapper.Contrib. Even if I were using Entity Framework, would I still not have to include a hidden field for the model's Id property inside my form? And if so, would that not also allow a user who is competent with dev tools to manipulate that hidden Id field and edit a different record?

Comment: You could store the key value in a hidden field. Or you could use sessions, although then you have to manage timeouts sensibly.  99% of apps have the key value in the URL of a CRUD page anyway. so you could just rely on that and then execute logic to ensure the user has permission to update the record associated with the key.